# Installing a cross-compiler on Ubuntu 13.10 (64-bit)

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to install a cross-compiler for i386-elf on my Ubuntu 13.10. I found instructions [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler). But when I enter the command `make all-target-libgcc`it says:

```
checking for suffix of object files...
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
```

I found this question twice on this site; once [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650493/checking-for-suffix-of-object-files-configure-error-cannot-compute-suffix-o?answertab=oldest#tab-top) and again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141454/compilation-gcc-4-6-2-cannot-compute-suffix-of-object-files). I looked at all the answers and tried them, but none of them worked. I found a comment on one of them telling me to try this:

```
aptitude build-dep gcc-avr binutils-avr
```

and then this:

```
install gcc-avr binutils-avr
```

But that is for avr and I am trying to compile for i386-elf. I am thinking that I might have this problem because I write `linux32`before each command. The reason I do that is because otherwise it gives me this error:

```
Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized
Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized
Unrecognized host system name x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.
```

when compiling the binutils. Can anyone tell me how to use the previous commands to build a cross-compiler for i386-elf? Or more solutions to try for that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no luck with that cross-compiler on ubunutu. But when I tried on [Debian](http://www.debian.org/) it worked. I also realized that I was using binutils-2.9 from the year 1997... no wonder why it does not know what x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu is!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while build the binutils from source file. The source file is downloaded from the GNU website.
I solved the problem by using "apt-get source binutils" to get the source. It looks like the source downloaded by this way including the patch to let it work on your OS.